# cannot count the size of an arraylist which contains two arrayllists

Tags: java, arraylist

I hope I can explain my question clearly:
There are three classes.

1. Class `Lamboghini` which is getting `modelYear`, `modelName`, `horsepower`, and `boolean`.
2. Class `LamboghiniCarLot` which has an arraylist inventory(add some `lamboghini` elements to it).
3. Class `LamboghiniDealershipGroup` which has arraylist carLots.
   Now, in `LamboghiniDealershipGroup` class, I try to make a method `public int getTotalInventoryCount()`;however, I cannot count the inventory correctly. My output always been 0. I think it might be because the way I added to  `arraylist` is wrong. But I don't know how to fix this problem.

---

```
public Lamborghini(int modelYear, String modelName, double horsepower, boolean isRearWheelDrive)
{
    setModelYear(modelYear);
    setModelName(modelName);
    setHorsepower(horsepower);
    setIsRearWheelDrive(isRearWheelDrive);
}
```

---

```
public class LamborghiniCarLot
{
    private String lotName;
    private ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory;


/**
 * creates the inventory ArrayList object;
 * the inventory remains empty (no Lamborghini objects are added when this constructor is called)
 */
public LamborghiniCarLot()
{
    inventory = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
}

/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 * 
 * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
 * @return     the sum of x and y 
 */
public LamborghiniCarLot(String lotName)
{

    setLotName(lotName);


    inventory = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1965, "350GT", 365.3, true));
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1966, "400GT 2+2", 366.3, false));
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1967, "MIURA", 367.3, true));
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1968, "espada", 368.3, false))


    }
public void setLotName(String lotName)
    {
        if(lotName != null)
        {    
            if(lotName.equals("Taylor's Used Lambos"))
            {
                this.lotName = "Jason's Used Lambos";
            }else
            {
                this.lotName = lotName;
            }
        }

    }

    public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini)
    {
        if(inventory != null && newLamborghini != null && inventory.size() > 0)
        {
            for(Lamborghini lambo : inventory)
            {
                if(lambo == null)
                {
                    inventory.add(newLamborghini);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getInventory()
        {
            return inventory;
        }}
```

then, the third class.

```
public LamborghiniDealershipGroup(String dealershipGroupName)
{

    setDealershipGroupName(dealershipGroupName);

    carLots = new ArrayList<LamborghiniCarLot>();
    //Create the first car lot
    LamborghiniCarLot carlot1 = new LamborghiniCarLot();

    carlot1.setLotName("Jason's vintage lambos.");
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1965, "350GT", 365.3, true));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1966, "400GT 2+2", 366.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1967, "MIURA", 367.3, true));


    //Create the second car lot
    LamborghiniCarLot carlot2 = new LamborghiniCarLot();

    carlot2.setLotName("Taylor's brand new lambos.");

    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2006, "gallardo", 506.3, true));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2007, "gallardo", 507.3, true));


    //Add them to the arraylist
    carLots.add(carlot1);
    carLots.add(carlot2);


}
```

and my method is here:

```
public int getTotalInventoryCount()
{
    int count = 0;


    for(LamborghiniCarLot c : carLots)
    {
        count += c.getInventory().size();
    }
    return count;
}
```

the method always get int 0. How can i fix it?

Comment: The `LamborghiniCarLot` class is missing a couple of methods (`addLamborghini(...)` and `setLotName(...)`). Can you also post those ?

Comment: What does `addLamborghini()` do? I notice you have two constructors for `LamborghiniCarLot`, one with name parameter that adds content and one without parameter that doesn't. Do you also have two constructors for `LamborghiniDealershipGroup`, and you're calling the other one that doesn't add anything? Also, please read "[How to create a **Minimal**, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Comment: i do have those methods, here i repost it already. please help

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `addLamborghini(...)` method, specifically, this condition `inventory.size() > 0`. The size of the `inventory` list is zero because you're using the no argument constructor (the one that doesn't add items to the list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *very* strange:

```
public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini newLamborghini) {
    if (inventory != null && newLamborghini != null && inventory.size() > 0) {
        for (Lamborghini lambo : inventory) {
            if (lambo == null) {
                inventory.add(newLamborghini);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's rattle off the conditions.

- If `inventory` isn't `null`...
- ...and `newLamborghini` isn't `null`...
- ...and there's at least one item in the inventory...
- Then we iterate over all items in the inventory.
- If one of those items is `null`...
- ...we add the `newLamborghini` into the inventory.

Almost all of this is unnecessary, and this is the chief reason why you're not inserting anything - your collection *starts* empty.  Even if it weren't, you don't add any `null` elements to it to satisfy the inner foreach loop.

You can reduce this to a saner check to see if the elements you're inserting are `null` and if the collection you're inserting it into is `null` instead.

```
if(inventory != null && newLamborghini != null) {
    inventory.add(newLamborghini);
}
```

If you eagerly initialized your `inventory` collection (by writing `ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory = new ArrayList<>();`), you could eschew the `null` check on `inventory`.

Comment: OMG! that's the reason my method can't get the size of arraylist. thank you sooo much!!!  I have been stuck in this problem a few hours. Again thank you for you patient answer : )

Answer (score 0):

You should add two below methods in your LamborghiniCarLot class. And it should work.

```
public void setLotName(String lotName) {
    this.lotName = lotName;
}

public void addLamborghini(Lamborghini lamborghini) {
    inventory.add(lamborghini);
}
```

Comment: Seriously, we assumed that he have that kind of code. But who knows, maybe your answer is right.

Comment: inventory.size() > 0. It's the problem. You're using no-arg constructor so the size of inventory is always zero and it never add new item.